# NASM Real Mode Addressing issue

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, mov

I've been following some tutorials about bios and stuff on Real Mode and tried to do the same as the author for reading special key press at 0417h.
He does something like this:

```
XOR AX,AX
MOV ES,AX
MOV AL,ES:[0417H]
```

But I only get "invalid combination of opcode" when doing the same on the third line. What could be the correct way of doing this in NASM?

Comment: `MOV AL,[ES:0417H]` See the [nasm manual section 3.3](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3)